# simplifing part of function code

Tags: r

I have very simple question, lets say i have function that generates random integer from chosen range, without generating zero. It goes like this:

```
customfunction=function(minv,maxv){
  value=floor(runif(1,min=minv,max=maxv))
  repeat {
    if (value<0){break}
    else if(value>0){break}
    else {value=floor(runif(1,min=minv,max=maxv))}
  }
  print(value)
}
```

Very simple. What i want to do is to make the part that restricts my function from generating zero to be just one sentence for example `zero_restriction`, in MY HEAD it would look like this:

```
customfunction=function(minv,maxv){
 value=floor(runif(1,min=minv,max=maxv))
 zero_restriction
  print(value)
}
```

Is this possible? Or is it too much of workaround to be worth? The point is I am going to have couple of functions each with certain restrictions, so i thought simplifying them to one word would be more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just using integers, one approach would be to exclude the values you don't want (such as 0) and use `sample` rather than `runif`...

```
customfunction <- function(minv,maxv){
  excl <- c(0) #values to exclude
  range <- seq(minv,maxv)
  range <- range[-which(range %in% excl)]
  return(sample(range,1))
}
```

Comment: Unfortunetly I will not be using only integers. I should emphasize at first post that this is only my training function, later on I want my function to take any value except 0.

Comment: This approach would work with any discrete set of values - not just integers - you just need to replace the `seq` with something that defines the set.  If you're planning to use real values then your chances of getting a zero are infinitesimal!

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider applying a while loop e.g.

```
while((r <- floor(runif(1, min, max))) == 0) {  }
print(r)
```

This may not be the most readable solution, but it will generate new random values, as long r is set to 0, and stop doing it after it is set to a non zero value.

Comment: as I just read you wont only be sampling integers. In this case this approach still works but I'd suggest a condition more like `abs(x) < 1e-6` and not an exact == test